# can someone check my answers and make sure i'm right

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

**Suppose you open a new bank account and on the first of every month you deposit your paycheck of $3000. Throughout the month you spend 30% of the money in your account. Let an be the amount of money in your account after the nth deposit (so a1 = 3000).**

**(a) Determine a2 and a3 explicitly.**

a2 = 3000 + .7*3000

a3 = 3000 + .7*3000 + .7^2 * 3000

**(b) Write out a simple formula (which should not include (summation/series symbol) or + . . . +) that can be used to determine the value of an for any n.**

an = (3000(1-.7)^n)/(1-n)

**(c) Determine lim n→∞ of an. Use this number to explain “In the long run”, what is the maximum and minimum
amount of money in your bank account on a month to month basis?**

0 dollars left in the long run.

Comment: Any time you write down a general formula for something, it's a good idea to run a "sanity check" by seeing what it says for a simple case or two. In this case, plug in $n=2$ or $3$ (or both) into the formula you got in part (b) and see if the result agrees with what you got for a2 and/or a3 in part (a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer for part (a) is correct. But when you extend the logic used there for arbitrary $n$, you should be obtaining
$$\begin{split}a_n&=3000+0.7\times 3000+0.7^2\times 3000+\cdots+0.7^{n-1}\times3000\\&=3000(1+0.7+0.7^2+\dots+0.7^{n-1}).
\end{split}$$
This is not the same as $3000(1-0.7)^n/(1-n)$. You have probably only made a careless mistake: notice that $1+a+\dots+a^{n-1}=(1-a^n)/(1-a)\neq(1-a)^n/(1-n)$. Can you fix this error yourself and therefore obtain the right answer for part (c) as well?